# If $W$ and $V$ are vector spaces what is $\Pi(W \oplus V)$?

Tags: notation, field-theory, physics, mathematical-physics, vector-bundles

The question is as the title says: If $W$ and $V$ are vector spaces what is $\Pi(W \oplus V)$? This is motivated from Costello's notes on supersymmetric field theories in 2 and 4 dimensions. There the supersymmetry algebra in the odd part is given as
$$ \Pi(S_{+} \otimes W \oplus S_- \otimes W^{*}) $$
Where $S=S_{+} \oplus S_{-}$ a spinorial representation and $W,W^*$ a vector space and its dual. What does this $\Pi$ stand for? I have been told it might be related to parity but I am not sure in what way.

Comment: We cannot really guess what someone uses that notation for...

Comment: I've seen that notation used to denote parity reversal, that is, $\Pi V$ is the super-vector space whose even part is the odd part of V and whose odd part the even part of V, but, as I said, it is impossible to guess what author X uses that notation for.  Ideally, the author explains that notation.

Comment: I also think it is what you say and the reason I ask is to see if anyone else has ever seen this before.

Comment: I have also seen that notation used to denote parity reversal and I'd be willing to bet it's the intended meaning.

Comment: @ QiaochuYuan thanks, I know this is related to the fact we have spinorial representation. Can you possibly comment on how a physicist should understand this?

Comment: Shouldn't you be asking physicists that? 

Comment: No, I ask specifically Qiaonchu since I know what he works on and he might  be able to answer this perfectly well. Physicists do not use this notation.